# "Getting started" on a Flash (Flex) website?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, swfobject

I want to create flash website, with flex, but i don't really know how it works so can you make it clear for me.

1) First of all i want to know how URL is working with flash, because every time i load new URL will flash website be reloaded? How to solve this problem, if it is problem?

2)I  want to use "`Swfobject`" with my flash website so this website will be Search Engines friendly and does this mean that i can easily use `Adsense` or `Adbrite` in my website?

Comment: You know that Adobe has [basically given up on Flex](http://blog.ness.com/spl/bid/72218/Adobe-is-being-disingenuous-with-Flex-Developers) (and [Flash on mobile devices](http://www.html5blog.org/2011/11/10/html5-wins/)), right?

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL For the future of Flex, look here: http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2011/11/your-questions-about-flex.html I feel it is incomplete to say they have given up on Flex.  ( Would you say they have given up on PhoneGap? The same day they announced the Nitobi acquisition they also announced it was being moved to the Apache Foundation )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't recommend creating a website in flash. These days more and more people are browsing through different devices such as the iPhone, which has no support for flash. A website in flash also generates a problem with search engines, your content won't be found by the search robots.

But, to answer your question:

1. Yes, if you click a "http://..." type link, the page will reload.
2. See above

Comment: +1 I believe Flash is a good choice for building many applications.  I wouldn't use it for a web site; and have avoided doing that since long before the iPhone existed.

Comment: You can use SWFAddress to allow for deep linking, so there doesn't necessarily have to be a reload.